Create new columns in dataframe with values from other columns based on condition
Let's say I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this(dots indicate more columns):
Type  Price1  Price2  Price3  Price4  Price5  ... ... 
A       nan     1       nan     nan     2           
A       nan     3       nan     nan     2
B       nan     nan     4       5       nan
B       nan     nan     6       7       nan
C       nan     2       nan     nan     1  
C       nan     4       nan     nan     3
D       1       8       nan     nan     nan
D       9       6       nan     nan     nan

I need to transform this dataframe to look like this:
Type   newcol1    newcol2  ...  ...
     A      2           1
     A      2           3
     B      4           5
     B      6           7
     C      1           2   
     C      3           4   
     D      1           8       
     D      9           6

These are the criteria for selecting which columns get which values:
if type == 'A'
'Price5' -> 'newcol1' && 'Price2' -> 'newcol2'

if type == 'B'
'Price3' -> 'newcol1' && 'Price4' -> 'newcol2'

if type == 'C'
'Price5' -> 'newcol1' && 'Price2' -> 'newcol2'

if type == 'D'
'Price1' -> 'newcol1' && 'Price2' -> 'newcol2'

My logic was to use the mask function to achieve this, and assign the values to 2 columns then just rename them, which works but I am handling every case seperately and is kind of messy:
df = df.mask(df['Type'].eq('A'), df.assign(**{'Price3': df['Price5'].values, 'Price4': df['Price2'].values}))

df.rename(columns = {'Price3':'newcol1'}, inplace = True) 
df.rename(columns = {'Price4':'newcol2'}, inplace = True)

 How could I achieve this in a more efficient manner?

You can use a custom groupby.apply with rename and reindex:
# dictionary to define the mappings per group
dic = {'A': {'Price5': 'newcol1', 'Price2': 'newcol2'},
       'B': {'Price3': 'newcol1', 'Price4': 'newcol2'},
       'C': {'Price5': 'newcol1', 'Price2': 'newcol2'},
       'D': {'Price1' :'newcol1', 'Price2': 'newcol2'},
       }

def f(g):
    # for each group, rename and select the columns
    d = dic.get(g.name, {})
    return (g.rename(columns=d)
             .reindex(columns=d.values())
           )

# apply the function per group
out = df.groupby('Type').apply(f).reset_index(0)

Output:
  Type  newcol1  newcol2
0    A      2.0      1.0
1    A      2.0      3.0
2    B      4.0      5.0
3    B      6.0      7.0
4    C      1.0      2.0
5    C      3.0      4.0
6    D      1.0      8.0
7    D      9.0      6.0


You can use np.select().
First define the mapping you want. I'm using a dataframe:
mapping = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'A': {'newcol1': 'Price5', 'newcol2': 'Price2'},
        'B': {'newcol1': 'Price3', 'newcol2': 'Price4'},
        'C': {'newcol1': 'Price5', 'newcol2': 'Price2'},
        'D': {'newcol1': 'Price1', 'newcol2': 'Price2'}},
    orient='index')

  newcol1 newcol2
A  Price5  Price2
B  Price3  Price4
C  Price5  Price2
D  Price1  Price2

Then create a list of conditions:
cond = [df['Type'].eq(k) for k in mapping.index]

Finally, use np.select():
# For this demo, I'm outputting to a new dataframe:
df_out = df['Type'].to_frame()

for new_col in mapping.columns:
    df_out[new_col] = np.select(
        cond,
        [df[old_col] for old_col in mapping[new_col]]
    ).astype('int')

  Type  newcol1  newcol2
0    A        2        1
1    A        2        3
2    B        4        5
3    B        6        7
4    C        1        2
5    C        3        4
6    D        1        8
7    D        9        6


P.S. pd.Series.case_when() is really similar to np.select(), but it's for replacing values, so I wouldn't use it here unless you considered one of the old_cols as a default for each new_col.

You can use lambda function:
df['newCol1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Price5 if x.Type == 'A' else (x.Price3 if x.Type == 'B' else (x.Price5 if x.Type == 'C' else (x.Price1 if x.Type=='D' else 'NaN'))), axis=1)
df['newCol2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Price2 if x.Type == 'A' else (x.Price4 if x.Type == 'B' else (x.Price2 if x.Type == 'C' else (x.Price2 if x.Type=='D' else 'NA'))), axis=1)


'NaN' and 'NA' aren't numeric, so they'll mess up the dtype. Use np.nan.
